# Namespace not found when I create an ADO.NET Entity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, ado.net

So I added a new item to my project "ADO.NET Entity Model" and Generated the model with an existing database in my localdb sql server. When I am trying to use the given namespace, is not finding it. Refer to my images below. How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you save your entity model? Code generation only happens on save...

Answer (score 0):

Probably something is missing from the Namespace. If you set the mouse caret inbetween `(` and `R` in the `using (RegionUnoEntities myEntities` line, the Visual Studio intellisense should show a red underline and then a small box, and if you click that, it should show the `using RegionUnoModel...` intellisense hint. Click that and it will add the correct using statement up on top.

[Here's more on using this feature of the Visual C# Intellisense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3shw4wa2.aspx).

If this doesn't work, you can right-click the `.EDMX` file for the **EF Model**, and click **View Code**, and then see the namespace that the `RegionUnoEntities` is defined in, and set that as the using statement in this file.

Comment: Intellisense is not finding it. It gives me two options, one to generate a new class for `RegionUnoEntities` and the other one to generate a new type.

Comment: Did you try the 2nd option? Going into the code of the .EDMX and then taking the namespace from the top there? Also, is your .EDMX in the same project as the RegionOne file?